# Jquery Click event - A Nightmare !

Tags: jquery

I have one link button with a click event. When Clicked I want to change its click event handler to call another method. I am using this :

```
$('#' + test).bind('click', function () { return LikeComment(test, CommentsWrapper, activityID, textAreaID, btnAddCommentID, addCommentBox, textUnLike, textLike, likeWrapperID); });
```

The next time it is clicked I bind it with this :

```
 $('#' + test).bind('click', function () { return UnLikeComment(test, CommentsWrapper, activityID, textAreaID, btnAddCommentID, addCommentBox, textUnLike, textLike, likeWrapperID); });
```

The thing is the handlers are buffering. the second time I click the link, the 2 methods are called.

Nothing helped. I used unbind() same thing.

Any suggestions ?

**More Info**

The initial status of the link button is like this :

```
  <a class='activitysmalllink' href='javascript:void' id='{0}' onclick='return LikeComment( ... ) '
```

When I click the LIKE link button, I invoke this code :

```
  $('#' + test).bind('click', function () { return deleteLikeComment(test, CommentsWrapper, activityID, textAreaID, btnAddCommentID, addCommentBox, textUnLike, textLike, likeWrapperID); });

 $('#' + test).text(textUnLike);
```

the weird thing is that this method is invoked as soon as I bind the link using the above following code.

Comment: $('#' + test).unbind('click').bind('click', function () { .... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unbind() unbinds events bound before with jQuery's bind.
But in your case the event initially is listed inside the element

```
<a onclick='return LikeComment...
```

...so it would'nt be affected by unbind()

Use attr() instead of unbind()

```
$('#' + test).attr('onclick','').bind('click','...')
```

...before binding the first time.
if you dont want to check if it's the first call, you could always use

```
$('#' + test).attr('onclick','').unbind('click').bind('click','...')
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. this code solved it :    $('#' + test).attr('onclick', '').unbind('click').bind('click', function () {

Comment: But it would also be a good solution to use the suggested toggle(). You just have to look, if there is a onclick-attribute present, if yes, remove it like shown above and bind the toggle, so you dont need any further bindings :)

Answer (score 2):

Something is messing up with your `unbind`: can you provide more code?

As an alternative (and prehaps, bette solution), how about [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) instead?

```
$('#' + test).toggle(function () { return LikeComment(test, CommentsWrapper, activityID, textAreaID, btnAddCommentID, addCommentBox, textUnLike, textLike, likeWrapperID); },
                     function () { return UnLikeComment(test, CommentsWrapper, activityID, textAreaID, btnAddCommentID, addCommentBox, textUnLike, textLike, likeWrapperID); });
```

You could also use [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one) instead of `bind()`

Comment: What does toggle does ?. My scenario is that I have a like link button, when the user click it, I will change it to UnLike and change its click handler.

Comment: @Joseph: Read the documentation I linked to. Toggle will alternate between the two functions on each click. It's impossible for `one()` to behave like that, it only fires' the event once. **Post more code**.

Comment: Matt, thanks for the help man. this did the trick :    $('#' + test).attr('onclick', '').unbind('click').bind('click', function () {

Answer (score 0):

You need to unbind click before you re-bind it.

Just put .unbind('click') in between $('#' + test) and .bind('click' for each statement.

Comment: I just did that. It keeps buffering the callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problm is with `$('#' + test).` define a variable first as `var a='#' + test;` then give the jquery statement as `$(a).`.

Comment: you can use toggle as matt said but with a currection give a click function adn inside it give the toggle function correct me if I am wrong

Comment: <a class='activitysmalllink' href='javascript:void' id='{0}' onclick='change();'></a> <script type="javascript">change(){if($(a).attr("onclick")=="return LikeComment( ...)"){$(a).attr("onclick")=="return UnLikeComment( ... ) }else{if($(a).attr("onclick")=="return LikeComment( ... )};</script>